Is a lock recommended in python when updating a bool in one direction in a thread, then reading it in another?
Is a lock necessary in a situation where thread 1 checks if a bool has flipped from False to True periodically within a loop, the bool being updated in thread 2?
As I understand a bool is atomic in python, it should not be possibly for the bool to be incorrectly updated or take on a garbage value like in C++ for example. Only one thread will ever update the bool, and it will only ever go from False to True (there is no position where it switches back to False). As the check is done periodically and timing is not critical, even if thread 1 reads the old value (False) while thread 2 is updating it to True, thread 1 should still be able to read the new value once thread 2 has finished on the next iteration of the loop.
Is this an incorrect understanding of this specific situation? I understand it is generally best to use locks, and I don't mind adding one, but I wonder if it would actually just be introducing more potential problems (like deadlocks) without actually solving any problem except maybe saving thread 1 from looping for one more iteration.
This is the loop in question. The two variables are being updated in another thread, and read in this one. Both are bool values starting as False and being set to True when the other threads have finished.
           while True:
                time.sleep(0.2)

                if self.joined_queries:
                    self.stop()
                    break

                if self.timeout:
                    self.stop()
                    break

There were some other threads but the answers were very general without going into specifics much, and the situation was a bit different. I would like to understand why this is a bad idea or not!
This piece of documentation makes me believe it is not a problem, but I am not really sure if I am interpreting it correctly: http://www.python.org/doc/faq/library/#what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe


As I understand a bool is atomic in python, it should not be possibly for the bool to be incorrectly updated or take on a garbage value like in C++ for example

Practically, a bool variable in cPython is going to be a pointer to one of the two objects Py_True or Py_False. The implementation details shouldn't matter, but it's relevant to know that a bool in Python will be exactly as atomic as a pointer in C.
In a cPython build without the GIL, this will be a data race and hence Undefined Behaviour according to the underlying C code.

This piece of documentation makes me believe it is not a problem

The page you linked explicitly says both that this sort of code is safe due to the GIL, and that work on removing the GIL to improve performance is ongoing. It seems unwise to write new code that depends on it.
Note that C's Undefined Behaviour may be perfectly well-defined on a given hardware platform, it's just non-portable. However, the code will be brittle in the face of newer interpreters and platforms.

thank you, I saw that part but was unsure of if I should be planning ahead but it makes sense to do so. I have implemented locks for these variables and I don't believe any issue should arise from using them in this context so I will stick to adding locks wherever reading or writing any data in the future!

There's an experimental GIL-less cPython build in 3.13. Who knows when it will become the default?

The part without the gil is not accurate, because whatever is holding that bool is storing it in a dictionary (object members are a dictionary) and that dictionary is locked when the bool pointer is modified, there is no undefined behavior here without the GIL, it is sequenced with the rest of the modifications, there is no data race, the only race is who gets to lock the mutex first

@AhmedAEK But is it true for local variables like here?

@nocomment the behavior of that code is currently well-behaved because the stack is also a dictionary, not sure if that will change in the future

@AhmedAEK Where's that dictionary? I don't think that's true. Local variables are stored in arrays and accessed with indices.

@nocomment i though it was accessing the locals() dictionary or something similar, which is not correct, it is grabbing the value from a Cell that contains the PyObject* almost like a dictionary, which is also protected by a mutex, so it is still thread-safe , not sure that will hold in the future though

I'm fairly sure it'll remain thread-safe on the nogil build. They work quite hard to make sure that the interpreter is kept in a consistent state which essentially means variable reads and writes are "atomic". (Of course you can write code that isn't thread-safe, but this particular case should be fine by design)
